# calculate proportion of interactions between values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that has a similar structure to this toy dataset. Rather than deal with binary data, I'd rather generate new columns that represent the interaction of values between the binary data columns (value1, value2, and value3) since there are only 8 possible combinations of values (e.g., TRUE.TRUE.TRUE, TRUE.TRUE.FALSE, etc.).

Specifically, I'd like to calculate the proportion of each combination per object and subject.

```
subject     object      value1     value2   value3 

1           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
1           A           TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
1           B           TRUE       FALSE    TRUE
1           B           TRUE       FALSE    TRUE
1           B           TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
2           B           TRUE       FALSE    FALSE
2           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
2           B           FALSE      FALSE    FALSE
3           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
3           B           FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
3           B           TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
...         ...         ...        ...      ...
```

Desired output:

```
subject     object      combination        value    
1           A           True.True.True    .5                 
1           A           True.True.False   .5   
1           B           True.True.True    .33
1           B           True.False.True   .67              
...
etc for subject 2 and 3...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
 df%>%
   group_by(subject, object)%>%
   mutate(val = str_c(value1,value2,value3,sep = "."),
          value = c(prop.table(table(val))[val]))
# A tibble: 11 x 7
# Groups:   subject, object [6]
   subject object value1 value2 value3 val               value
     <int> <chr>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <chr>             <dbl>
 1       1 A      TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE.TRUE.FALSE   0.5  
 2       1 A      TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE.TRUE.TRUE    0.5  
 3       1 B      TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   TRUE.FALSE.TRUE   0.667
 4       1 B      TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   TRUE.FALSE.TRUE   0.667
 5       1 B      TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE.TRUE.TRUE    0.333
 6       2 B      TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  TRUE.FALSE.FALSE  0.5  
 7       2 A      TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE.TRUE.FALSE   1    
 8       2 B      FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE.FALSE.FALSE 0.5  
 9       3 A      TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE.TRUE.FALSE   1    
10       3 B      FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE.TRUE.FALSE  0.5  
11       3 B      TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE.TRUE.TRUE    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), object = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "B"), value1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), value2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), value3 = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

#Code
df %>% mutate(value=paste(value1,value2,value3,sep = '.')) %>% group_by(subject,object,value) %>%
  summarize(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(subject,object) %>% mutate(Prop=N/sum(N))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   subject, object [6]
   subject object value                 N  Prop
     <int> <chr>  <chr>             <int> <dbl>
 1       1 A      TRUE.TRUE.FALSE       1 0.5  
 2       1 A      TRUE.TRUE.TRUE        1 0.5  
 3       1 B      TRUE.FALSE.TRUE       2 0.667
 4       1 B      TRUE.TRUE.TRUE        1 0.333
 5       2 A      TRUE.TRUE.FALSE       1 1    
 6       2 B      FALSE.FALSE.FALSE     1 0.5  
 7       2 B      TRUE.FALSE.FALSE      1 0.5  
 8       3 A      TRUE.TRUE.FALSE       1 1    
 9       3 B      FALSE.TRUE.FALSE      1 0.5  
10       3 B      TRUE.TRUE.TRUE        1 0.5
```